# Using maybePop and pop

Tags: flutter

I know that `maybePop` and `pop` have a similar function for popping screen to previous screen, but `maybePop` has a return value of `Future<bool>` and this can be useful for some cases like avoid to return a black screen when the widget tree is on the first layer.

If `maybePop` itself can handle popping and more 'safe' than `pop`, Is there any condition or reason that I should use `pop` instead of `maybePop`?

Comment: I thinks that can be apply where you don't need a callback. That may effect on your RAM and processing time. Other than that seems like no any other benefit of using ```pop```

Comment: `pop` will ignore the `WillPopScope` widget and force you to go back to previous page. But `maybePop` can't do that.

Comment: @Argon: Is it 'significantly' affect the performance?

Comment: @Ampersanda with the modern tech specs comes with the latest devices i hope not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your use case. [Navigator.pop()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) doesn't interact with the [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) callback if that's what you're using. On the other hand, [Navigator.maybePop()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/maybePop.html) works well in `WillPopScope` and is asynchronous because it takes `WillPopScope` takes an asynchronous callback.

Here's a [blog post](https://medium.com/lost-but-coding/the-dark-side-of-navigator-pop-c6c210ac37e7) discussing the difference of `pop` and `maybePop` in detail.

Comment: A paid article...